# UI5 NetworkGraph basic example is not working

Tags: sapui5

I downloaded this [UI5 ​​sample](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/sample/sap.suite.ui.commons.sample.NetworkGraph/preview). After that i downloaded also the graph.json dataset from the example and tried to run it. It does not run and breaks off. I guess it's the layout.

```
<layoutAlgorithm>
    <layout:LayeredLayout
        mergeEdges="{settings>/mergeEdges}"
        nodePlacement="{settings>/nodePlacement}"
        nodeSpacing="{settings>/nodeSpacing}"/>
</layoutAlgorithm>
```

As soon as I use the ForceBasedLayout it works. But if I use the LayeredLayout instead I get an Exception.

I get the following error and the NetworkGraph remains busy:

[image: Console Screenshot]

ForceBasedLayout (this is working):

[image: ForceBasesLayout]

LayeredLayout (this is not working - **this is what i want to use**):

[image: LayeredLayout]

NetworkGraph.view.xml (with LayeredLayout):

```
<mvc:View
    controllerName="sap.suite.ui.commons.sample.NetworkGraph.NetworkGraph"
    xmlns="sap.suite.ui.commons.networkgraph"
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
    xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"
    xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
    xmlns:layout="sap.suite.ui.commons.networkgraph.layout"
    xmlns:m="sap.m"
    height="100%">
<l:FixFlex vertical="true">
    <l:fixContent>
        <m:OverflowToolbar>
            <m:content>
                <m:Select id="orientation" tooltip="Orientation" selectedKey="{settings>/orientation}">
                    <core:Item key="LeftRight" text="Left-Right"/>
                    <core:Item key="RightLeft" text="Right-Left"/>
                    <core:Item key="TopBottom" text="Top-Bottom"/>
                </m:Select>
                <m:Select id="nodePlacement" tooltip="Node placement" selectedKey="{settings>/nodePlacement}">
                    <core:Item key="BrandesKoepf" text="Brandes-Koepf"/>
                    <core:Item key="LinearSegments" text="Linear Segments"/>
                    <core:Item key="Simple" text="Simple"/>
                </m:Select>
                <m:Select id="arrowPosition" tooltip="Arrow position" selectedKey="{settings>/arrowPosition}">
                    <core:Item key="Start" text="Arrow Start"/>
                    <core:Item key="Middle" text="Arrow Middle"/>
                    <core:Item key="End" text="Arrow End"/>
                </m:Select>
                <m:Select id="arrowOrientation" tooltip="Arrow orientation"
                          selectedKey="{settings>/arrowOrientation}">
                    <core:Item key="ParentOf" text="Parent -> Child"/>
                    <core:Item key="ChildOf" text="Child -> Parent"/>
                    <core:Item key="None" text="Hidden"/>
                </m:Select>
                <m:Select id="mergeEdges" tooltip="Merge Edges" change="mergeChanged" selectedKey="0">
                    <core:Item key="0" text="Split edges"/>
                    <core:Item key="1" text="Merged edges"/>
                </m:Select>
                <m:Select id="nodeSpacing" tooltip="Node Spacing" selectedKey="55" change="spacingChanged">
                    <core:Item key="20" text="Node spacing (20)"/>
                    <core:Item key="40" text="Node spacing (40)"/>
                    <core:Item key="55" text="Node spacing (55)"/>
                    <core:Item key="80" text="Node spacing (80)"/>
                    <core:Item key="100" text="Node spacing (100)"/>
                </m:Select>
            </m:content>
        </m:OverflowToolbar>
    </l:fixContent>
    <l:flexContent>
            <m:FlexBox fitContainer="true" renderType="Bare" wrap="Wrap" id="graphWrapper">
                <m:items>
                    <Graph
                            orientation="{settings>/orientation}"
                            nodes="{/nodes}"
                            lines="{/lines}"
                            groups="{/groups}"
                            id="graph">
                        <layoutData>
                            <m:FlexItemData growFactor="1" shrinkFactor="1" baseSize="0%"  minWidth="300px"/>
                        </layoutData>
                        <layoutAlgorithm>
                            <layout:LayeredLayout
                                    mergeEdges="{settings>/mergeEdges}"
                                    nodePlacement="{settings>/nodePlacement}"
                                    nodeSpacing="{settings>/nodeSpacing}"/>
                        </layoutAlgorithm>
                        <nodes>
                            <Node
                                    key="{key}"
                                    title="{title}"
                                    icon="{icon}"
                                    group="{group}"
                                    attributes="{path:'attributes', templateShareable:true}"
                                    shape="{shape}"
                                    status="{status}">
                                <attributes>
                                    <ElementAttribute
                                            label="{label}"
                                            value="{value}"/>
                                </attributes>
                            </Node>
                        </nodes>
                        <lines>
                            <Line arrowPosition="{settings>/arrowPosition}"
                                    arrowOrientation="{settings>/arrowOrientation}"
                                    from="{from}"
                                    to="{to}"
                                    status="{status}">
                            </Line>
                        </lines>
                        <groups>
                            <Group key="{key}"
                                    title="{title}">
                            </Group>
                        </groups>
                    </Graph>
                    <GraphMap id="map" graph="graph">
                        <layoutData>
                            <m:FlexItemData minWidth="200px" maxWidth="25%" />
                        </layoutData>
                    </GraphMap>
                </m:items>
            </m:FlexBox>
    </l:flexContent>
</l:FixFlex>
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: I downloaded the sample and graph.json, copied your NetworkGraph.view.xml  (& added a </mvc:View> at the end) and everything runs fine on my machine. Did you try this with a different browser? Can your try it on a different PC?